# facial shape segmentation

Tags: c#, java, python, aforge

I need to know if it's there a way, with AForge or similar libraries, to develop an application that extract from a picture the facial shape. I mean: the application take a picture, detect the face, recognize face contour, trace this contour and delete what's inside. So at the end the application return an image (a portrait) without the face, but with hairs and other image elements. I've seen there are many questions about image's shape detection, but my question is particular cause face have not a default shape, but some facial features used by face detection algorithms. I'd like to know if it's possible and in which way to use these features to trace the facial shape. 
anybody could help me? 
thanks - luke

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a very good generic computer vision library which includes face detection. It also has Python bindings, so you're good to go. There are plenty of [tutorials](http://creatingwithcode.com/howto/face-detection-in-static-images-with-python/) on using it (just Google around). I wish you the best of luck with your project.